# Does buildozer work on OSX/ios?

Tags: ios, kivy, buildozer

I've written an app that works on Linux, Windows and OSX, and Android via kivy and buildozer

I've got it running now on ios using the [Kivy documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html)

But on ios how do you use the elements that buildozer takes care of in an android build, in particular the orientation and the icons?

Comment: Maybe you can call the ios api for this using pyobjus (the same way you can use pyjnius on android).

Comment: Thanks. That may be possible. But I have chosen to develop my app in kivy precisely because I did not want to have to write code based upon multiple target OSs. It rather loses the point if, for every little problem, you have tinker under the bonnet

Comment: See [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer) for a platform-independent interface to specific platform apis. If you have to tackle a not-currently-implemented api, you could contribute it back so that everyone can use the platform independent interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted out both the problems

The icon simply the file Icon.png in the

```
kivy-ios/<your app id>-ios
```

directory.

The orientation can be controlled by using

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
```

and then in the Build method

```
  Window.rotation+=<the orientation you want>
```